# Getting a cropped image from ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I use ImageView to crop a bitmap.
Once it is cropped I want to get that cropped image, but I get the same as the original.
Is there a way to get only the viewable part of the image?

```
ImageView iv = new  ImageView(this);                        
iv.setImageBitmap(OriginalBitmap);
iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
Bitmap CroppedBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

The value of CroppedBitmap is as the OriginalBitmap. How can I get the cropped one?

Comment: Bitmap CroppedBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(originalbitmap,bitmap.getWidth()/2 - bitmap.getHeight()/2,
   0,
   bitmap.getWidth()/2 + bitmap.getHeight()/2, 
   bitmap.getHeight()
   );

Comment: What do I get with this? My OriginalBitmap reduced to a half?

Comment: What's your exact need, at which dimension you must crop

Comment: Ok, I tell the user to select a picture of himself. Then that file is drawn inside an 100x100 ImageView. That is way I write ScaleType.CENTER_CROP or other modifiers. With this I should get that picture zoom in or zoom out and center. Then I want to get that portion of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

This [example](http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-GetCrop-the-visible-portion-of-ImageView-/2676/) works for me
`iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap croppedBitmap = iv.getDrawingCache()`

Answer (score 0):

This following code for crop the image 200x200

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
           R.drawable.android);

    int width = bitmapOrg.width();
    int height = bitmapOrg.height();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                      width, height, matrix, true); 

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

    iv.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the picture looses proportions. It deforms. I would need to keep proportions like ImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP) does.